# Creating and accessing a global constant in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, singleton, angularjs-service

Does anyone know the best way to create and access a global constant is AngularJS?

I want to be able to doe something like:

```
app.constant('baseURL','http://www.baseurl.com');
```

and access it from any factory or controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going for constant would be one of the better way as it has ability that we can access it inside the `config` level or in `provider`, so that we can take use of them to carry the config level settings.

For usage you could inject the same way as we do inject for `service/factory` or consider any dependency.

For making it more better you could use Object inside the your `app.constant`, so that it can carry multiple settings in it.

**Constant**

```
app.constant('configSettings', {
   'baseUrl': 'http://www.baseurl.com',
   'someElseSetting': 'settingValue'
   //other setting will also be there.
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, configSettings){
   //console.log(configSettings.baseUrl);
   //you could use base URL here
});
```